# Graphing y=x^2 and y=x

Tags: graphs

I want to draw the region bounded by y=x^2 and y=x. Any ideas? I was hoping this would be somewhat simple. I've tried used a similar, with \begin{axis}..\end{axis}, but it doesn't like that. Did I not declare a package or something?

Also, if I wanted to show the solid this region creates by rotating it about the x-axis, is there a way to did this in latex? (If you had cal 2, think volume of a solid rotated about ...).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Plotting a 2D region is relatively easy. But doing 3D requires a different package. :)

Comment: [Is this what you had in mind?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ttWR2.png)

Comment: @Alenanno yes, but only want the first quadrate, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, plotting a function in 2D is relatively easy in `pgfplots`, and with the version 1.10 filling between is even easier.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=0, ymax=10
    ]

    \addplot [name path=plot1, ultra thin, domain=-10:10, samples=150]{x^2};
    \addplot [name path=plot2, ultra thin, domain=-8:8]{x};

    \addplot[red] fill between[of=plot1 and plot2, soft clip={domain=0:1}];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```