# Filling an area between curves

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've recently started to write a Calculus material, topic "Area Between Curves". I'm trying to fill the area between those graphs as shown in the picture, but I haven't had success:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=0.5, help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-1.5,-1.5) grid (4,4);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-1.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-1.5) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[dashed,scale=3,domain=-0.4:0,smooth,variable=\x,red, thick] plot ({\x},{\x*\x});
    \draw[name path=F, scale=3,domain=0:1,smooth,variable=\x,red, thick] plot ({\x},{\x*\x});
    \draw[dashed,scale=3,domain=1:1.1,smooth,variable=\x,red, thick] plot ({\x},{\x*\x});
    \draw[dashed,scale=3,domain=-0.4:0,smooth,variable=\x,blue, thick] plot ({\x},{\x});
    \draw[name path=F, scale=3,domain=0:1,smooth,variable=\x,blue, thick] plot ({\x},{\x});
    \draw[dashed,scale=3,domain=1:1.2,smooth,variable=\x,blue, thick] plot ({\x},{\x});
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Is using tikz the best approach? How can I make those three variations of filling the areas?

[image: Area_between_curves]

Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with `pgfplots`? It has a dedicated library called `fillbetween` which can also be used in TikZ. But I would really encourage you to use `pgfplots` for this.

Comment: I gave an answer time ago with exactly the first plot, and I have seen the second one on this site too.

Comment: Found it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245844/4778 in that case, it clips the negative x, but the logic is the same.

Comment: Please always post a complete minimal example. Mere fragments of code are much less useful. (And how can you have checked it will compile when completed in a standard way without completing it in a standard way to check? So you might as well post the complete version....)